# How to use hide/show function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, button, hide, show

I have one `HTML` page with one toggle button and some drop down item. My toggle button is like on-off.
What i need??   I need to hide drop down item when i click on "ON" and show drop-down when i click
on "off". I am very newbie on `HTML , CSS, JQuery`. Here is my code of HTML file which work only
for toggle.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/iphone-style-checkboxes.js" type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"
charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
   body {padding: 10px; }
 th {text-align: right;padding: 4px;padding-right: 15px;vertical-align: top; }
.css_sized_container .iPhoneCheckContainer {width: 250px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.on_off :checkbox').iphoneStyle();
  $('.disabled :checkbox').iphoneStyle();
  $('.css_sized_container :checkbox').iphoneStyle({
     resizeContainer: false, resizeHandle: false
  });
  $('.long_tiny :checkbox').iphoneStyle({
     checkedLabel: 'Very Long Text', uncheckedLabel: 'Tiny'
  });

  var onchange_checkbox = ($('.onchange :checkbox')).iphoneStyle({
    onChange: function(elem, value) { 
      $('span#status').html(value.toString());

    }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    onchange_checkbox.prop(
     'checked', !onchange_checkbox.is(':checked')).iphoneStyle("refresh");
    return
  }, 2500);
});

</script>  
</head>
<body>
  <table><tr class="on_off">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="on_off" />
    </td>
  </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

I know following function use for hide and show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").click(function(){
      $("p").hide();
   });
    $("#show").click(function(){
      $("p").show();
   });
});
```

But i don't understand how this function implement in `javascript`.
  because above function work on two button and i use only one button..
  Please give me any hint or direct  me where i wrong?....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toggle` method:

> Display or hide the matched elements.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("p").toggle();
});
```

Or according to your markup:

```
$("#on_off").change(function(){
     $("p").css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `.toggle` to bind two different handlers to a button. e.g. `$('#button').toggle(hideHandler, showHandler);`

Comment: @Onchie That `toggle` has been deprecated http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this;

***HTML***

```
<p>Hello</p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
```

***JSCODE***

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
     $('p').slideToggle();
})
```

**OR**

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
     $('p').toggle();
})
```

Comment: sorry for the first time there was spelling mistake now you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

See as per your requirement you do not need to use 2 function calls.
You can use toggle method which will perform both functions.
Refer below sample:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
 $("p").toggle();
});
```

Also for giving effects while hiding any element refer below link:

[Effects for Hide in Jquery](http://aspdotnetraining.blogspot.in/2013/11/jquery-hide.html)

Answer (score 0):

By normal is just a way is

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
$("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
$("p").show();
});
```

go through this link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp